# Pod file breakpoints are not working in xcode 10.1 whereas its working on older version of xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.1

I have one project created on XCode 9 with cocoa pods integration and debugging with breakpoints are working on this version of xocde but breakpoints are not working on XCode 10.1, However I am able to put the breakpoint on the file but it doesn't stop on that point. Could anyone have any idea about the same?